# How to get the instanceId of an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

How to get the instanceId of an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance in cloudformation?

I've created an elastic beanstalk using an `elasticbeanstalk Template` and an `elasticBeanstalk environment`. Now I need to reference somewhere to the instanceId of that EB. How can I do this in cloudformation?

Or can I use some workaround to get the underlying EC2 instance from my EB somewhere, and then just get the instanceID of that EC2 (which works).

Here is a part of my template. I have an EIP and I want to associate it with the instanceId of my EB EC2. The last line does not work (instanceId)

```
Resources:
  ProxyEIP:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::EIP"
  ProxyEIPAssocation:
     Type: "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation"
     Properties:
      InstanceId: !GetAtt ProxyEnvironment.InstanceId
```

I have a basic config for my elastic beanstalk. Here I want to create an environment property for my IP.

```
  ProxyConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !ImportValue ProxyApplication
      OptionSettings:
      ..
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: NGINX_IP
        Value: !Ref ProxyEIP
```

Which is used by my environment

```
  ProxyEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      EnvironmentName: !Sub "Proxy-${Environment}"
      ApplicationName: !ImportValue ProxyApplication
      TemplateName: !Ref ProxyConfiguration
      CNAMEPrefix: !Sub "nginx-${Environment}"
```

Comment: Can you explain more the scenario of what you are trying to do?  Are you needing the InstanceId during the first initialization of your environment?  Or during an update of your environment?  Any more details on your overall goals and requirements would be helpful to us to try and solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CloudFormation CustomResource to invoke the lambda function.

Where your lambda will describe the Elastic Compute Cloud Instances based on the Tags Key provided by ElasticBeanstalk to the EC2 Instances, get the instance Id.

Lambda function will send response to CloudFormation endpoint